# Search function is not returning the value

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I just started to learn tree and was implementing it using c language. I think I made the program for tree(Binary Search Tree) But while searching the value and printing wheather the element was found or not the search function is not returning the value correctly (or wrong value) 
I am hereby attaching the code

```
// to search in binary search tree
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct bstnode
{
    int data;
    struct bstnode *left;
    struct bstnode *right;
};

struct bstnode *insert(struct bstnode *,int);
int search(struct bstnode *,int);

void main()
{    
    int n,s,n1;
    char ch;
    struct node *root;
    clrscr();
    root=NULL;
    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter a number\n");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        root=insert(root,n);
        printf("\nDo You Wish to enter more\n");
        ch=getch();
    } while(ch=='Y'||ch=='y');

    printf("Enter a number to search");
    scanf("%d",&n1);
    s=search(root,n1);
    if(s==1)
        printf("Found");
    else
        printf("Not found");
    getch();
}

struct bstnode* insert(struct bstnode *root,int data)
{
    struct bstnode *newnode=(struct bstnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct bstnode));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->left=NULL;
    newnode->right=NULL;
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root=newnode;
    }
    else if(data<=root->data)
    {
        root->left=insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right=insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return(root);
}

int search(struct bstnode* root,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
        return 0;
    if(root->data==NULL)
        return 1;
    else if(data<=root->data)
        return(root->left,data);
    else
        return(root->right,data);
}
```

Please Help!!!!

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: What do you think `return(root->left, data)` will do? You need to call the `search` function recursively, but you're just returning `data` with that.

Comment: `if (root->data == NULL)` is wrong. `data` is an `int`, `NULL` should be used with pointers.

Comment: @Barmar I have rectified that error but still my problem is not solved

Comment: root pointer should be of type **struct bstnode***

Answer (score 1):

Your `search` function has two problems:

1. It never checks whether it found `data`. Instead it checks for `root->data == NULL`, but that's not correct.
2. It should be calling itself recursively on the left or right subtrees, but it's not.

The correct code is:

```
int search(struct bstnode* root,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL) {
        return 0;
    } else if(root->data==data) {
        return 1;
    } else if(data<=root->data) {
        return search(root->left,data);
    } else {
        return search(root->right,data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Now you have rectified my problem Thanks again and please keep helping me out

Comment: I hope you will study more so you don't have to come here to get other people to debug your programs for you. You'll never make it as a programmer if you don't learn that.